# (Presto Kafka connector) How to convert unstructured message to structured?

Tags: apache-kafka, presto

I have troubled by an issue for a long time.
The data in kafka is somewhat like the following:

```
presto:default> select _message from topic_2874_1 limit 5;

2016-10-24 17:12:39,1200032544,IRC7D184YIF6,a44fb5306d966921dc6b0faa5395e6662fc58c43,1477300352,5.1.6,02:00:00:00:00:00,223.104.10.244,4,CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE,223.82.245.18,238,62,inews.gtimg.com,/newsapp_ls,200,SDWebImageDownloader,11092,0,0,1,,
2016-10-24 17:12:39,1200032544,IRC7D184YIF6,d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e36b64515,1477300347,5.1.6,02:00:00:00:00:00,183.38.234.248,4,WiFi,inews.gtimg.com,19,24,inews.gtimg.com,/newsapp_bt,200,QNImageLoaderRequest,51692,0,0,1,,
2016-10-24 17:12:40,1200032544,IRC7D184YIF6,4df4c5a34cca33c14ce9e351f82fba32cc5336b5,1477300359,5.1.6,02:00:00:00:00:00,123.138.243.146,4,WiFi,113.200.90.144,24,18,inews.gtimg.com,/newsapp_ls,200,SDWebImageDownloader,14922,0,0,1,,
2016-10-24 17:12:40,1200032544,IRC7D184YIF6,c32cedd56561780129d0967e1a7e6811d60f9ea4,1477300351,5.1.5,02:00:00:00:00:00,117.136.84.177,4,CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE,183.232.121.140,227,1,r.inews.qq.com,/reportActualExpose,200,ASIFormDataRequest,29,0,0,1,,
```

It’s naturally not like json type; and every field separated by comma is very likely don’t have the same length. So how can I convert those log message to structured data for future SQL querying?  I read the presto document about kafka connector word by word, but still could not get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the schema of the data up front, you can set up a topic description file (steps 5 and 6 of the Kafka tutorial): https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/kafka-tutorial.html#step-5-add-a-topic-decription-file.

Basically, this topic description file is a json file in `etc/kafka` that maps fields in Kafka to columns in Presto.

Note: if you're using the RPM to install Presto, you will need to change the topic description directory by setting `kafka.table-description-dir=/etc/presto/kafka` in `kafka.properties`. Then, your table description files should be located in `/etc/presto/kafka`.